# What is devideId, in this case of encrypted data?

Tags: json, payment-gateway, deviceid

This data is submitted upon making a payment to a shop. I know what everything is inside this request, BUT the deviceId. I wonder if any of you can help me understand what it is? I have thought maybe it is the IP used to make the purchase, encrypted of course.

```
  "deviceId": "0400JapG4txqxq87tK3Sga2t5uGwIuibBnbfdv2d5xZpQAbc9yfK90jDe4Ex7yacWI+PSJ8LtkUO2KrmqwzdkqV85rx7E+KKiREzaGixPMqjFULp6y1Wn9dxJb2CXaiWs2BQ01yVHsJBqLj+Tz8r1LuD3pEhNxlJSkYJNTlGEOTFo0fwefn5Dp+vHPQYQ2a+MNO+10W2U662Zn31Ya5FvP78HAIkYKDcfC9D4Vi63SxaUDEWMvbAv+zYzmvDClNrGBrqq8OzQ7EJK3MQykNtv5sxfitUVQo=",
  "cartId": "7001f4e8-6807-4ea3-a09a-81056c2bb8d0",
  "encryptedCardNumber": "adyenjs_0_1_18$aCUkFm+aTjTas2ZOksfD+DE4k5H0CiGe+VPbN3yt7VYH6dcSjV76kjfV/PzRD7u3oOn/BIANHgfa1gdxx7jaLAMEJkvFDcdIQFR9nscs95A50efvYfBW+EFo0AvALa7pO/pLM/xF64ZMP/zCsmbEJZU7TmsMNl2V4vxYcO1nXL3UXcTp7YgAc8oOFOD2/fES/FvJEmrd0TvYYQsz5wbMKAyA==$KMU6gGGzJQPLtDL/tVnqA1CnS61b2LyERu/6RJa1eeOzZt822OSr8FHV+iG12GKt9+F9r/KDXA50/YlK8tBrlA9aOCtVw5Dt1Qa/EqBqKulUjnXU47NyzS0nLggUL5TRNXMnz1Mk8IRBcxhwyjdd/uEdBSV4BLN6qj0P67J5Ygq8CZuJ3g01xeZ0P57CyySwfsfP38=",
  "encryptedExpiryMonth": "adyenjs_0_1_18$SvF/NlwiMfG2h8SuKf6XSsPhrSSlbk4u2AJBHvNmPPHVRTe+dQkKs1GLPiDZjnEKcDWm/pPnPmLHTars3oSkVDZQTTAy21Z2oWZ9h0ldpJqw/aoLtTZ8VNvGAu7xghrpN8Xyxf0rYQ0VgiQV3mGngLhGbO4jkGljp0oMoxHNrQN+b1bceMv8WHZCL/NWTjQ/OptEuRaYkcRS3NmK6YAwU4dIEFEE+MDIfZj6+7rh5dBaVh/hBBn9zTIO9QJa6NV6jQVsYM=",
  "encryptedExpiryYear": "adyenjs_0_1_18$tWbi3JHBeClQtDAkILmpDSvhJO1ci27+q9MPc5lxJt5",
  "encryptedSecurityCode": "907mhbTaKUS6NTbQ8Oko8DfuiSbi9wqECxfIP50yJ+q1NPgfLn0kPodH1U3fEpBE4x/bm4pNmwjyjIikrcme+smAsQzXU82dWa9mFsjW8hE/k61Y3f547lLRuHftOUVxZttA==",
  "paymentMethod": "CREDITCARD",
  "returnUrl": "xxxxxxx",
  "browserInfo": {
    "screenWidth": 1382,
    "screenHeight": 864,
    "colorDepth": 24,
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0",
    "timeZoneOffset": -60,
    "language": "en-US",
    "javaEnabled": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Impossible to know without some context, look at the documentation of the service you're using. But most likely it's either a random, unique string or some sort of fingerprint condensed somehow. In any case, it's only useful for you for telling if it's the same computer using the service twice or it's a new user.

Comment: It's some data to identify the device (hence the name) but it's quite impossible to know for anyone except the shopprovider (or the developer of the used platform), what is really used to generate this id ...

Comment: I see I am on a pretty hard job, finding out how this deviceId is generated :D Thank you both for your inputs, appreciate it!